# Same parameter type constructors auto deduction

Tags: c++11, c++17

I have a class whose constructor accepts const string &.
When I use auto to define a object with string as parameter. The type deduction result is a string, instead of my custom class.
Which rule does apply here?

```
class AB{
    public:
    AB(const string& a){
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    string a {"a"};
    auto b("b"s);
    
    cout<<a<<endl<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for `auto` to construct your `AB` from a `string`. Why should it pick your `AB` class instead of the many other classes that accept a string in their constructor?

Comment: This is exactly my question. Which deduction rule is applied here. Why it picks string ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Placeholder type deduction](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct):

> *Placeholder type deduction* is the process by which a type containing a placeholder type is replaced by a deduced type.
>
> A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding *initializer-clause **E***, are determined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - For a variable declared with a type that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the declared type of the variable.
>
> [...]
>
> - - If the initializer is a parenthesized *expression-list*, the *expression-list* shall be a single *assignment-expression* and ***E*** is the *assignment-expression*.
>
> [...]
>
> If the *placeholder-type-specifier* is of the form *type-constraint<sub>opt</sub>* `auto`, the deduced type `T`<sup>′</sup> replacing `T` is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. [...] Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of *type-constraint<sub>opt</sub>* `auto` either with a new invented type template parameter `U`[...]. Deduce a value for `U` using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call, where `P` is a function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is ***E***. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, `T`<sup>′</sup> is obtained by substituting the deduced `U` into `P`.

---

So according to the rule, when you have the statement `auto b("b"s);`, `"b"s` is considered the *initializer-clause **E***, and the deducting type of `b` is `T`. The deduction would work as passing ***E*** to a templated function:

```cpp
template <class U> void f(U u);
```

with a call like `f(E)`, and the deducted `T` will be obtained from `U`. Since your ***E*** is `"b"s`, and passing that to the templated function will result `U` to be an `std::string`, hence `b` is deducted to be a `std::string`.

---

If you want to force `b` to be of `AB` type, you can rewrite you code to something like:

```cpp
auto b = AB("b"s);
```

or:

```cpp
auto b(AB("b"s));
```

or for C++17 or later you can also do:

```cpp
auto b{AB("b"s)};
```